# Is it possible to restrict access to a Facebook page wall until a user has liked it?

Tags: facebook

The title sums it up but basically I was interested to know if it is possible to hide the wall of a Facebook page until someone has liked it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not to the whole page but to certain tabs (own apps) you define. this is called a fan gate.
see http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php for an example.

Comment: Okay, that method looks quite simple. Am I right in presuming Facebook won't let us do a similar thing to our wall? I.E. Only letting liked users access the wall.

Comment: fan pages are per definition public content. read is possible even for not loged in users. writing/commenting is only possible for fans.

Comment: for non-fans you can set on which "tab" the users should come, this is often the fan-gate page. so non-fans dont come to the wall directly (but can klick the link of course)

Comment: Okay, I'll just alter the landing page and make it my app. Thank you!